How to use raw PCM audio data as a custom audio source in WebRTC on Android?
I'm integrating WebRTC into my project (using Java library), and as I can see, it can use pre-defined audio sources like microphone.
I've already implemented a custom audio source that generates PCM data, but I'm struggling to figure out how to inject this data into WebRTC's audio pipeline. I couldn't find any clear documentation or examples on how to achieve this.
Here are my questions:

Is it possible to use raw PCM data as an audio source in WebRTC on Android?
If so, how can I inject the PCM frames into WebRTC's audio capture pipeline?
Are there any specific classes or interfaces in the WebRTC library that I should be using for this purpose?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

My guess is that this will depend largely on what WebRTC implementation you are using. Are you using this one?

@CommonsWare yes. Isn't it just a pre-built "default" impl from Google with some utility extensions? I can use any open-source implementation, if this one doesn't fit.

You have to send an SDP message to other peer specifying that you use a pcm codec with this line: a=rtpmap:97 L24/48000/2 This is the link you have to read:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elemental-live/latest/ug/2120-sdp-audio.html

This isn't exactly a Java question, but maybe rather a C++/JNI question.
Whatever implementation one looks at, they all just wrap native assembly.
And this assembly would generally support your requirement: wav_file.cc.
This is what provides the jingle_peerconnection.so; for example:

Java wrapper for a C++ AudioSourceInterface.
Used as the source for one or more AudioTrack objects.

In order to get there, one might have to expose more native methods through JNI;
eg. one which permits passing a file-name and one which permits switching the stream.
Or even PCM with voice-over; it all depends which methods the JNI (glue) might expose.
If you'd build the assembly from source, you'd get the debug symbols, to set breakpoints.
This makes it a whole lot easier to deal with, because one doesn't deal with a black box.
